# K-Means Clustering Not Working As Expcected

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, python, k-means, scikit-learn

I have a script that I'm testing with in Python3 with Scikit to cluster terms based on either words or character n-grams. Basically, it's fed a list of training data with corresponding labels. For example:

```
Name            Label
mexican food    1
greek cuisine   1
hotel night     7
...
airfare         7
```

After I run the program I type in raw input which should be transformed and predicted. However, no matter what I put it, the program makes the same prediction. This occurs even if I put in a term such as 'mexcian' which only appears once in the training data and hence should be trivial to predict. Can anyone spot the issue?

```
from __future__ import print_function

from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from sklearn import metrics

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, MiniBatchKMeans

import logging
from optparse import OptionParser
import sys
from time import time

import numpy as np


# Display progress logs on stdout
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')

# parse commandline arguments
op = OptionParser()
op.add_option("--lsa",
              dest="n_components", type="int",
              help="Preprocess documents with latent semantic analysis.")
op.add_option("--no-minibatch",
              action="store_false", dest="minibatch", default=True,
              help="Use ordinary k-means algorithm (in batch mode).")
op.add_option("--no-idf",
              action="store_false", dest="use_idf", default=True,
              help="Disable Inverse Document Frequency feature weighting.")
op.add_option("--analyzer",
              type='str', default='word',
              help="Which analyzer to use. Valid options are 'word' and 'char'")
op.add_option("--use-hashing",
              action="store_true", default=False,
              help="Use a hashing feature vectorizer")
op.add_option("--n-features", type=int, default=10000,
              help="Maximum number of features (dimensions)"
                   " to extract from text.")
op.add_option("--verbose",
              action="store_true", dest="verbose", default=False,
              help="Print progress reports inside k-means algorithm.")

print(__doc__)
op.print_help()

(opts, args) = op.parse_args()
if len(args) > 0:
    op.error("this script takes no arguments.")
    sys.exit(1)

opts.analyzer = opts.analyzer.lower()
assert opts.analyzer in ['word','char']

###############################################################################
# Read in the data
inputfile = '../data/dodcategories.csv'
data = np.loadtxt(inputfile,dtype=[('type','|S16'),('subID',np.int),('ID',np.int)],delimiter='\t',skiprows=0,unpack=True)
X = np.array([str(item,'utf-8').lower() for item in data[0]])
labels = np.array(data[1])
true_k = np.unique(labels).shape[0]


print("Extracting features from the training dataset using a sparse vectorizer")
t0 = time()
if opts.use_hashing:
    if opts.use_idf:
        # Perform an IDF normalization on the output of HashingVectorizer
        hasher = HashingVectorizer(n_features=opts.n_features,
                                   stop_words='english', non_negative=True,
                                   norm=None, ngram_range=(1, 10), binary=False, analyzer=opts.analyzer)
        vectorizer = make_pipeline(hasher, TfidfTransformer())
    else:
        vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(n_features=opts.n_features,
                                       stop_words='english',
                                       non_negative=False, norm='l2',
                                       binary=False, ngram_range=(1, 10), analyzer=opts.analyzer)
else:
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5, max_features=opts.n_features,
                                 min_df=2, stop_words='english',
                                 use_idf=opts.use_idf, ngram_range=(1, 10),analyzer=opts.analyzer)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(X)

print('------------------------------------------------')
print("done in %fs" % (time() - t0))
print("n_samples: %d, n_features: %d" % X.shape)
print()

if opts.n_components:
    print("Performing dimensionality reduction using LSA")
    t0 = time()
    # Vectorizer results are normalized, which makes KMeans behave as
    # spherical k-means for better results. Since LSA/SVD results are
    # not normalized, we have to redo the normalization.
    svd = TruncatedSVD(opts.n_components)
    lsa = make_pipeline(svd, Normalizer(copy=False))

    X = lsa.fit_transform(X)

    print("done in %fs" % (time() - t0))

    explained_variance = svd.explained_variance_ratio_.sum()
    print("Explained variance of the SVD step: {}%".format(
        int(explained_variance * 100)))

    print()


###############################################################################
# Do the actual clustering

if opts.minibatch:
    km = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', n_init=1,
                         init_size=1000, batch_size=1000, verbose=opts.verbose)
else:
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1,
                verbose=opts.verbose)

print("Clustering sparse data with %s" % km)
t0 = time()
km.fit(X,labels)
print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))
print()

print("Homogeneity: %0.3f" % metrics.homogeneity_score(labels, km.labels_))
print("Completeness: %0.3f" % metrics.completeness_score(labels, km.labels_))
print("V-measure: %0.3f" % metrics.v_measure_score(labels, km.labels_))
print("Adjusted Rand-Index: %.3f"
      % metrics.adjusted_rand_score(labels, km.labels_))
print("Silhouette Coefficient: %0.3f"
      % metrics.silhouette_score(X, labels, sample_size=1000))

print()

if not (opts.n_components or opts.use_hashing):
    #print("Top terms per cluster:")
    order_centroids = km.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
    terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    #for i in range(true_k):
        #print("Cluster %d:" % i, end='')
        #for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
            #print(' %s' % terms[ind], end='')
        #print()

test = 'test';   
while test.lower() not in ['exit','',None]:
    test = input("Enter a category (Type exit to quit): ")
    X_test = [test.lower()]
    print("Test: {}".format(X_test))
    X_test = vectorizer.transform(X_test)
    print("Test: {}".format(X_test))
    result = km.predict(X_test)
    print("Result: {}".format(result))
```

Comment: As a basic check, you may want to see what clusters the model assigned to the training data. One problem with using vector-space methods in Text Mining is the curse of dimensionality...pretty soon every test point appears extremely far from all the others, so distinctions become harder...at some point, they may all be assigned the same "default" class...you may have several. See Sec 2.4 here: http://www.cs.utah.edu/~piyush/teaching/kmeans50yrs.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

k-means:

- does not work well for high-dimensional data
- is sensitive to noise (and text is very noisy)
- not a *classification* algorithm

I'm not surprised it doesn't work, because you are looking for a *classifier*, not a clustering algorithm.

Try looking at the frequency of your clusters. I wouldn't be surprised if almost everything ends up in the same megacluster, and the other "clusters" are wasted on some outliers. That would be the typical (useless) result of k-means on such data sets. Sorry, k-means is not a magic bullet.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the difference between clustering and classification...very different but often confused aims.